# How to control decimal places in mtable output in R?

Tags: r, decimal

Can I please get your help on extending decimal places in mtable output in R? It currently shows only 1 decimal place, but would like to see those in 5 decimal places. Thanks!

```
m1<-lm(formula=Sales~Price.Eggs,data=sales.data)
m2<-update(m1,.~.+Ad.Type)
m3<-update(m2,.~.+Price.Cookies)
mtable(m1,m2,m3)


======================================================
                      m1          m2          m3      
------------------------------------------------------
  (Intercept)     115.366***  101.571***  137.370***  
                  (10.041)     (9.899)    (10.834)    
  Price.Eggs      -19.286***  -16.643***  -16.118***  
                   (2.263)     (2.166)     (1.646)    
  Ad.Type: 1/0                  4.195**     4.147***  
                               (1.371)     (1.040)    
  Price.Cookies                            -8.711***  
                                           (1.901)    
------------------------------------------------------
  **R-squared         0.7         0.8         0.9     
  adj. R-squared      0.7         0.8         0.9**     
  sigma               3.9         3.4         2.6     
  F                  72.6        51.8        67.1     
  p                   0.0         0.0         0.0     
  Log-likelihood    -82.5       -78.1       -69.2     
  Deviance          431.2       320.3       177.2     
  AIC               171.1       164.2       148.4     
  BIC               175.3       169.8       155.4     
  N                  30          30          30       
======================================================
```

Comment: You can set the`sdigits` parameter in `mtable`. Check `?mtable`

Comment: Wow it worked! THANK YOU!!